# how do i change the text of the "Add to cart" button in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, translation

I have tried different plugins and short codes but nothing works.
At the start it worked fine but then all of a sudden it switched from danish ("Tilføj til kurv"), which is the text i made myself, to english ("Add to cart") and now i can't change it back.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woocommerce_custom_add_to_cart_text'); 
function woocommerce_custom_add_to_cart_text() {
return __('Tilføj til kurv', 'woocommerce');
}
```

This code goes to your function.php child theme

Comment: Thank you for your help but im afraid it doesnt work. Or maybe im just putting it in the wrong place. Where do i find the function.php child theme?

Comment: yourdomain/wp-admin/theme-editor.php in the right sidebar, you will see "function.php"

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', function( $text ) {
    if ( 'Read more' == $text ) {
        $text = __( 'View Product', 'woocommerce' );
    }
```

Change the 'Read more' on second line to what the current text is in your button. then change 'EXAMPLE' to what you wish the text to be. This will not apply to buttons where products are 1. out of stock and 2. variable products